# Timestamp from small float numbers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I have an array like this:

```
var myArray = [[2.55555e-12, 1],[2.55556e-12, 2],[1.1111e-11, 3],[2.77778e-11, 4]]
```

And I need transform values : 2.55555e-12, 2.55556e-12, 1.1111e-11, 2.77778e-11 to timestamp so I can use it in highcharts.

Comment: What does the numbers represent? it's impossible to answer your question without some background knowledge.

Comment: I think that they should be representation of seconds.

Comment: But those are decimal values. The first one represents the value 0.00000000000255555000. That wouldn't make (much) sense as seconds. You need to know with absolute certainty what those numbers are supposed to represent before you can transform them into anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `string.split('e-')` (assuming all of these numbers require exponentiation). Then, use the contents of the array to multiply your numbers into a new array. For example,

For 2.55555e-12 = 2.55555 * 10^-12:

```js
    var myArray = [[2.55555e-12, 1],[2.55556e-12, 2],[1.1111e-11, 3],[2.77778e-11, 4]]
    var newArray = [];
    for (var i in myArray) {
        var tempArray = myArray[i][0].toString().split('e');
        if (tempArray.length > 1) {
            newArray[i] = tempArray[0] * Math.pow(10, Number.parseFloat(tempArray[1]));
        } else {
            newArray[i] = Number.parseFloat(tempArray[0]);
        }
    }
    console.log(newArray);
```

For 2.55555e-12 = 2.55555 * 10^12:

```js
var myArray = [[2.55555e-12, 1],[2.55556e-12, 2],[1.1111e-11, 3],[2.77778e-11, 4]];
var newArray = [];
for (var i in myArray) {
  var tempArray = myArray[i][0].toString().split('e-');
    if (tempArray.length > 1) {
        newArray[i] = tempArray[0] * Math.pow(10, Number.parseFloat(tempArray[1]));
    } else {
        newArray[i] = Number.parseFloat(tempArray[0]);
    };
};
console.log(newArray);
```

### Edits

- changed parseInt to parseFloat
- changed splitting expression and added data validation for regular floats
- corrected final number calculation and added another for question ambiguity

Comment: This is just the snippet of data but not all numebers has e- form. Array starts with those values but later there a regular floats like 0.022478095858007717, 3.928926074160278, 8.668202778

Comment: @DuFuS what do the second numbers in the arrays represent? Also, I am not sure how the array is formatted (if "2.55555e-12" means (2.55555^12) or (2.55555^-12).

Comment: You could just use `(2.55555e-12).toFixed(20)`. That'll format the number to a fixed-point decimal string. The number 20, is the number of decimals you want to include.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen Agreed in terms of neat-ness, but still do not think that I should assume to what power we are raising. For example, (2.55555e-32).toFixed(20) would result in all 0's. If only the asker were more descriptive.

Comment: The scientific notation Xe-Y doesn't represent X^Y but X * 10^Y. So your calculation should be `2.55555 * Math.pow(10, -12)`. But agreed, we certainly need some semantics to how this value has anything to do with a timestamp. If it's a timestamp, it's an incredibly short interval.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen Ah, my mistake again, corrected. This still displays numbers with (e-...), which is what the (now MIA) asker was looking to avoid I believe, but highcharts itself takes these kinds of numbers so I'm not sure what the asker was trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi guys problem solved. Thank you for answers and additional question it helps me to rethink my problem I discovered that I don't need to convert the data to timestamps. Those are realy small values and highcharts can handle it without convertion.

Comment: @DuFuS please mark as correct answer or edit your question to [solved] in case others have the same question.